# leet-code search insert position: why my binary search cannot return the right answer

Tags: python, binary-search

```
class Solution:

def recursive_binary_search(self, nums: list[int], target: int, base: int):
    if (len(nums) == 1):
        return base

    position = int((len(nums) - 1)/2)

    if (nums[position] == target):
        return base + position + 1
    elif (nums[position] > target):
        base = base + int((len(nums) - 1) / 2)
        return Solution.recursive_binary_search(self, nums[position+1:], target, base)
    elif (nums[position] < target):
        return Solution.recursive_binary_search(self, nums[:position+1], target, base)

def searchInsert(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> int:
    return Solution.recursive_binary_search(self, nums, target, 0)
```

[image]

the question requirement is:
Given a sorted array of distinct integers and a target value, return the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.

You must write an algorithm with O(log n) runtime complexity.

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your algo is making recursive call to the function with update new array and base. Beasue out this your base and array value are keep changing on each call and you are not maintaining the index if the value is find or not. also to call class method use `self.<method name>` not `class.<method name>`. A simple
a simple result

```
class Solution:
    def recursive_serach(self, low, high):
        if low<=high:
            mid = low +(high-low)//2
            if self.nums[mid]==self.target:
                return mid
            elif self.nums[mid]<self.target:
                return self.recursive_serach(mid+1, high)
            elif self.nums[mid]>self.target:
                return self.recursive_serach(low, mid-1)
        return low
        
    def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target 
        
        low, high = 0, len(nums)-1
        if self.target<self.nums[low]:
            return low
        if self.target>self.nums[high]:
            return high+1
        if low<=high:
            return self.recursive_serach(low, high)
            
            
        return low
```

Instead of passing the updated list and updated base, just pass the lower index and upper index of search range.